# Fan vs. Air-conditioning

Tags: fluid-dynamics, temperature, air, flow, fan

At the office, we have the air-conditioning turned on like crazy, and we are therefore freezing...

The air-conditioning is coming from the roof.

My question is:

Does putting a fan blowing in the opposite direction of the air conditioning (i.e. from the desk to the ceiling) helps reducing the effect of the air conditioning (by effect, I mean cold and air flow)? In other words, does the fan can cancel out the AC effect, assuming for simplicity that the two air flows have the same speed / amplitude?

Any technical / non-technical explanations are welcome.

Comment: I would point the fan so it's blowing cold air at the thermostat.

Answer (score 2):

It could diminish the blowing effect in particular direction, but AC blows out cold air, so temperature will still drop at the same rate overall. Working fan does heat up air a little bit (since it's an electrical device), but it's negligible compared to ACs' efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

I deal with a similar issue in my bedroom and the answer to your question about the fan is no and yes. The fan does make spots directly in line of the A.C. warmer as it directs the cold air of the A.C. away but it makes other parts of the room ,less accessible to A.C. air, more cooler. All this is true for about the first 30 minutes to 1 hour of start of operation of the A.C. But after more time when the room has reached a temperature close to the one on A.C. remote then the fan actually helps cool better as it helps to even out the cooling pushing air by cycling it.